# Why am I getting this error? SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: angularjs

Why am I getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
"Application": "abc",
```

This is the page I'm getting the error on:
http://hoteldemo.t15.org/#/

I can't see anything wrong with my code.  The JSON data is returned and displayed on the page so it all works - just need to get rid of the error.

```
    .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "js/main.html",
                controller: "configCtrl",
                controllerAs: "controller",
                resolve: {
                    myData: ["httpDataLoader", function(httpDataLoader){
                        return httpDataLoader.load();
                    }]
                }
            })
    }])

    .controller('configCtrl', ['$scope', 'myData', function($scope, myData){
     this.data = myData.data;
     console.log(myData.data)
     //  this.config = myData.data;
     //  console.log(this.config)
    }])

    .service("httpDataLoader", ["$http", function($http) {
      this.load = function() {
        return $http({url: "js/config.json"});
      }
    }])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
<script src="js/config.json"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="js/config.json" type="application/json"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error becuase you have this in your view:

```
<script src="js/config.json"></script>
```

Src attribute specifies the URL of an external java script file not a JSON file.
In your json file you have the following:

```
{
    "Application": "abc",
    "Key": "12345",
    "SharedSecret": "54321"
}
```

The JSON object is not valid JavaScript. I don't know what you want to obtain but I think you have two options: 
1. use your json file to store js object in literal notation.
2. remove script tag and load file using ajax.